# Web3 dart transaction stuck at pending

Tags: flutter, dart, web3dart

I'm relatively new to Flutter and blockchain and I'm trying to create simple app. For start i create my own wallet and it is OK, I get credentials and address. I get balance with web3 getBalance method, and gas info with estimateGas and getGasPrice.

When I want to send some coin using sendTransaction method, I get the transaction hash, but when I check it on polygonscan it is stuck on pending status.

I'm sure addresses are OK, because I can coin from my metamask wallet and it is updated in my app.

Here is the code:

```
await _web3client.estimateGas().then((value) async {
  maxGas = value.toString();
  var result = null;
  await _web3client.getGasPrice().then((value) async {
    print(value);
    try {
      var transaction = Transaction(
        to: EthereumAddress.fromHex(controller.text),
        gasPrice:
            EtherAmount.fromUnitAndValue(EtherUnit.wei, value.getInWei),
        maxGas: int.parse(maxGas),
        value: EtherAmount.fromUnitAndValue(EtherUnit.ether, 5),
      );

      result = await _web3client.sendTransaction(_credentials, transaction,
          chainId: 80001);

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(result.toString()),
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 5)));
      await _web3client.dispose();
      print(result.toString());
    } catch (error, trace) {
      print("Error: " + error.toString());
      print("Trace " + trace.toString());
    }
  });
});
```